# Start Google Maps for navigation not working when using longitude and latitude

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I have my longitude and latitude values in my andoroid app and i am passing them to the url as the official android docs says, like so -

```
 String query_string = "google.navigation:q=" +location.getLatitude()+","+location.getLongitude();
 Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse(query_string);
 Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
 //mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
 startActivity(mapIntent);
```

Google maps opens up quiet alright but it allows says route cant be found.

[image]

And i can see the longitude and latitude values i passed in the Google maps address bar. It shows 'finding best route' then shows the error message 'no route found'. It also happens in all modes (walking, driving....). Not Sure why.

Comment: Can you share values of lat,lng? Also, what is your current position? Can you try [Google Maps URLs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide) as the latest (2017) and recommended by Google way to generate map links?

Comment: xomena i added an image to the post

Comment: Why is `mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");` commented out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had a look at your screenshot. I can see that you try to find a driving directions from your current location to coordinate 3.2949945,6.5993606.

However, the 3.2949945,6.5993606 is located in the water inside Gulf of Guinea. You can see this in geocoder tool:

https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/utils/geocoder/#q%3D3.294995%252C6.599361

[image]

I guess your intention is to find a route to the 6.5993606,3.2949945:

https://developers-dot-devsite-v2-prod.appspot.com/maps/documentation/utils/geocoder/#q%3D6.599361%252C3.294995

Comment: Yes thats the intention. Let me try to adjust my code and swap the latitude and longitude values and see what happens.

Comment: The problem was i saved the longitude as latitude and the latitude as longitude in the program.